# "Type of expression is ambiguous without more context" when creating UInt16 array from Bluetooth characteristic

Tags: swift, type-conversion

I am using Xcode 9.2 and I don't understand the reason behind the error

> Type of expression is ambiguous without more context

I am getting some input  when trying to create and wordArray as showed below. If I define it as UInt8 array it does work but not if I do as Uint16 since I get the error.

The original data, Characteristic.value comes from a BLE characteristic

```
let characteristicData = Characteristic.value

let byteArray = [UInt8](characteristicData!)
print("\(Characteristic.uuid) value as byte is->",byteArray)

let wordArray = [UInt16](characteristicData!)//Type of expression is ambiguous without more context
print("\(Characteristic.uuid) value as word is->",wordArray)
```

Why does this happen and how I can fix it?

Comment: What’s the type of `characteristicData`? It can either be a sequence of `UInt8` or `UInt16`, it can’t be both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`characteristicData` has the type `Data` and that conforms to the
`(RandomAccess)Collection` protocol with `UInt8` as element type, that's why you can
initialize an `[UInt8]` array from it:

```
let byteArray = [UInt8](characteristicData)
```

You could equivalently write

```
let byteArray = Array(characteristicData)
```

To interpret the data as an array of a different type, use
the generic

```
func withUnsafeBytes<ResultType, ContentType>(_ body: (UnsafePointer<ContentType>) throws -> ResultType) rethrows -> ResultType
```

method:

```
let wordArray = characteristicData.withUnsafeBytes {
    [UInt16](UnsafeBufferPointer(start: $0, count: characteristicData.count/2))
}
```

Here the `ContentType` is inferred automatically as `UInt16`.